# Does "Nugget" term has a special meaning in CSS context?

Tags: html, css

I have seen lots of class names containg word 'Nugget' in one css file.

I would like to ask in terms of CSS, does the word 'nugget' has some known special meaning?

Thanks

Comment: "one css file"? 1) It's just *one* file. 2) *What* file?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... more likely it has a "special meaning" in the context of what it's being applied to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no recognised standard to class naming and no special class names within the CSS or HTML specifications.

However your class name of 'nugget' may have special meaning in the context of your *site*, not the CSS/HTML standards.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. Nugget is not a CSS term.

Comment: +1 As close to web development as it gets, it's commonly used to refer to small bits of ASP.NET code interspersed within view files. But there's nothing about CSS.